# Does this C++ code Swap the first and last bits?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

```
void Tools::Swap(uint32_t number){
    int temp1 = (number >> 31) & 1;
    int temp2 = number & 1;
    int ans = number & 7ffffffe;
    int mask = (temp2 << 31) | temp1;
    ans = ans | mask;
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

I've worked it out on paper and it does seem to swap the first and last bits but I want to be sure it's the best way I can be doing this.

Comment: Might have something to do with your argument being an unsigned integer, but all your local variables being signed. Try using `uint32_t` for all types, and print the *hexadecimal* values before and after.

Comment: It looks like it works to me.

Comment: Oh, and the code you show wont actually even compile, that hexadecimal integer literal is missing something crucial...

Comment: Yeah it seems to work. I think you should post this on codereview.stackexchange. That is the correct place

Comment: it might be more readable if you did something like `if (high bit is 1) { if (low bit is 0) { bitwise operation here } } else { if (low bit is 1) { bitwise operation here } }`

Comment: I'd advise using `uint32_t` throughout the function. Currently, if `temp2` is negative then the behaviour of `<<` will be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

No. `(temp2 << 31)` causes undefined behaviour if `temp2` is `1`, and `int` is 32-bit or narrower.

However, if you replace all of the `int` by `uint32_t` and slap an `0x` on the front of `7ffffffe`, then it seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to let the compiler create temps as needed. With shift counts of 31, there's no need to use &.

```
uint32_t number;
    // ...
    number = (number<<31) | (number & 0x7ffffffe) | (number>>31);
```